# Design Pattern for a Specific Wrapper Class

Tags: design-patterns

I’m trying to figure out the best approach for designing a wrapper class I’m working on.

I have a class, `class A`.  It has a handful of public methods.  I have a second class, `class B`, which is used to manage many pointers to instances of `A`.  `A` should be hidden from the user and only accessed through `B`, but this isn’t a hard rule could be broken.  `B` needs to provide the user all the same methods that `A` has, for each pointer, by simply wrapping `A`‘s functions.

My question is, do I simply wrap `A`’s functions?  This seems problematic because anytime I add a function to `A`, I must write a wrapper function in `B`, which seems like redundant code.  The other option is to write one single function that returns one of the pointers to `A`, so the user could use `->` on it and access all of `A`’s methods.  In this case, no extra methods need to be written in `B` whenever one in `A` is added.  The issue with this solution is that it exposes `A`, which I really don’t want to do, but will if necessary.

Is there a current design pattern that cleanly deals with this?  Or some preferred method?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a language-specific answer; but in general, have you looked at the Decorator and/or Proxy patterns?

Comment: I suppose you’re right.  Specifically, C++, but in general, anything that supports pointers and classes.  Also, I’ll look into your design pattern suggestions, thanks.